# Ember.Logger.log is deprecated and console.info gives 'no-console' build warnings, what to do?

Tags: ember.js

I'm relatively new to Ember development, but keen to do things the right way.

For logging, I used to use `Ember.Logger.log('blah');` but that now throws warnings in the console that it's deprecated. There's a link in the warning to https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v3.x#toc_use-console-rather-than-ember-logger, which recommends using `console` instead.

So I switch to `console.info('blah');`, but now when I do `ember serve` there's a bunch of "problems" like:

```
/Users/mick/Projects/Pop Up Eats/Vendor Website/app/routes/application.js
  22:3  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console
  27:3  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

What am I supposed to do? Am I missing something?

Comment: that's just a linter thing. if you want to keep console in your code you'll need to disable that linting rule. :)

(or change the level to warning, instead of error)

Comment: Also there are many good tools for logging out there. Tools that allow you to send your logs over the network for example...

Comment: Where you need to use console methods, you can add `//eslint-disable-line no-console` in the end of a line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an Eslint error. 
You can change it to be a warning/not an error anymore by going to your .eslintrc.js file and by adding this to your rules:

```
rules: {
  "no-console": 0  //which turns the rule off
 }
```

OR

```
rules: {
  "no-console": 1  //which will just warn you about the console logs
 }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed.